# python regex, substitute patterns in a string

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace some substrings in a string with wiki markup. E.g. I have a string

```
some other string before
; Methods
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Anomaly detection|Anomaly/outlier/change detection]]
* [[Association rule learning]]
* [[Statistical classification|Classification]]
* [[Cluster analysis]]
* [[Decision trees]]
* [[Factor analysis]]
* [[Neural Networks]]
* [[Regression analysis]]
* [[Structured data analysis (statistics)|Structured data analysis]]
* [[Sequence mining]]
* [[Text mining]]
}}

; Application domains
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Analytics]]
* [[Bioinformatics]]
* [[Business intelligence]]
* [[Data analysis]]
* [[Data warehouse]]
* [[Decision support system]]
* [[Drug Discovery]]
* [[Exploratory data analysis]]
* [[Predictive analytics]]
* [[Web mining]]
}}
some other string after
```

I want to replace the original substring by

```
[[Anomaly detection|Anomaly/outlier/change detection]]
[[Association rule learning]]
[[Statistical classification|Classification]]
[[Cluster analysis]]
[[Decision trees]]
[[Factor analysis]]
[[Neural Networks]]
[[Regression analysis]]
[[Structured data analysis (statistics)|Structured data analysis]]
[[Sequence mining]]
[[Text mining]]
[[Analytics]]
[[Bioinformatics]]
[[Business intelligence]]
[[Data analysis]]
[[Data warehouse]]
[[Decision support system]]
[[Drug Discovery]]
[[Exploratory data analysis]]
[[Predictive analytics]]
[[Web mining]]
```

I've tried some regex expressions to extract stuff in {{ }} first. But I always got None.

ADD: The problem is that I'm only interested in the contents in [[]] which itself is in {{}}. I have some other occurrences of [[]] in other part of the string.

So, how could I do this by using re.sub? Thanks

ADD: current solution (ugly)

```
def regt(matchobj):
  #store matchobj.group(0) somewhere else, later on add them to the string
  #Next, another function will remove all {{}} alway
  return ''

matches = re.sub(r'\[\[.*?\]\](?=[^{]*\}\})', regt,wiki_string2)
```

Comment: Use [wiki parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers)! Regex are meant for regular languages.

Comment: I tried re.sub(r'{{.*?}}', ' ', string), re.sub(r'\{\{.*?\}\}', ' ', string) and other more complicated re expressions I found online. I got the full string back.

Comment: Hi JBernardo. Currently, I'm able to remove most wiki markups from the article. In my parser, I remove every occurrence of {{}}. I hope I could keep the contents in the tables. I found some wiki parsers online but these parsers only turn the wiki markups to html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Match** it instead of `replacing` it

```
\[\[.*?\]\](?=[^{]*\}\})
```

---

`.*?` matches lazily.so it would stop at the first time `]]` occurs

`.*` matches greedily.so it would stop at the last time `]]` occurs

---

`(?=[^{]*}})` is a `lookahead` which means match content within `[[ ]]` only if it is followed by 0 to many characters except `{` till `}}`..

This is done because you want to match ``` [[``]] ``` if it is within `{{` `}}`..

So characters after `]]` would be any character except `{` till `}}`..

So this would avoid cases like this

```
[[xyz]]<-this would not match since { after it
{{
[[xyz]]<-this would match since it is not followed by { and it reaches }}
[[xyz]]<-this would match since it is not followed by { and it reaches }}
}}
```

Comment: Hi Some1.Kill.The.DJ. I hope to extract contents in [[]] which itself is in {{}}. It's a table in wiki markup.

Comment: Hi Some1.Kill.The.DJ. Thanks for the reg expression. Very cool! I'm not familiar with reg expression. Do you mind explaining a little bit what does [^{] mean or providing me with some pointers? Thanks.

It works if I just want to find the occurrences. I use another function regt to get and keep the contents and later on add the contents to the string again. 
    def regt(matchobj):
      #store matchobj.group(0) somewhere
      return ''
 
    matches = re.sub(r'\[\[.*?\]\](?=[^{]*\}\})', regt, string)

Any more elegant solution?

Comment: Hi Some1.Kill.The.DJ. Got it. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use non-greedy regexp, with something like:
    r"\{\{.*?\}\}"

Comment: Hi shenshei. It doesn't work. re.match(r'{{.*?}}', string) returns None.

Comment: sorry, I got a problem with the \\

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
In [10]: p = "\[\[.*?\]\]"
In [11]: s1 = '\n'.join(re.findall(p, s))
```

**Update**
With your additional constrain (only text inside {{}} matches) you can achieve your goal in two steps:

- select the text inside braces
- then select the text inside square braquets

You can do it as follow (I use a source string containing text in square braquets that doesn't match):

```
In [157]: print s
some [[other string before]]
Methods("")
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Cluster analysis]]
* [[Decision trees]]
* [[Factor analysis]]
}}
Application("domains")
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Analytics]]
* [[Bioinformatics]]
* [[Web mining]]
}}
some [[other string after]]

In [158]: p = "(?:\{\{)[\s\S]*?(?:\}\})"

In [159]: s1 = '\n'.join(re.findall(p, s))

In [160]: print s1
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Cluster analysis]]
* [[Decision trees]]
* [[Factor analysis]]
}}
{{columns-list|3|
* [[Analytics]]
* [[Bioinformatics]]
* [[Web mining]]
}}

In [161]: p1 = "\[\[.*\]\]"

In [162]: s2 = '\n'.join(re.findall(p1, s1))

In [163]: print s2
[[Cluster analysis]]
[[Decision trees]]
[[Factor analysis]]
[[Analytics]]
[[Bioinformatics]]
[[Web mining]]
```

Comment: Hi Vicent. Thanks. Still, I hope to extract contents in [[]] which itself is in {{}}. I got some occurrences of [[]] in other part of the string.